# MariaDB Load Data Infile JSON

Tags: json, mariadb

I have searched a lot but haven't found a way to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` with a JSON and automatically adding data to equivalent columns.

Imagine a `People` table, with `ID` and `Name` fields.
And a json with the following structure:

```
[
    {"Name": "Tom", "ID": 7},
    {"Name": "Sara", "ID": 8},
    {"Name": "Laura", "ID": 9},
    {"Name": "John", "ID": 10},
    {"Name": "Felicia", "ID": 11},
    {"Name": "Carl", "ID": 13}
]
```

Any way to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to this json file and MariaDB map the keys and add value to correspondent fields?

Comment: Check [CONNECT JSON Table Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-json-table-type/) for ideas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.  You must write a loop in some programming language to walk through the JSON array.